# text-overflow: ellipsis not working with inline-flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does `text-overflow: ellipsis` not work when I use `display: inline-flex` or `display: flex`? My requirement is that I have to use a flexbox.

```css
.test {
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<label class="test">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, itaque, at error rerum ab facere cupiditate veniam incidunt modi temporibus explicabo earum molestiae minima facilis a excepturi laborum similique dolore.
    </label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work on anonymous flex items. Wrap the text in a `span`, and apply the ellipsis there.

```css
.test {
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: cyan;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label class="test">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, itaque,
            at error rerum ab facere cupiditate veniam incidunt modi temporibus
            explicabo earum minima facilis a excepturi laborum similique</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `inline-flex` on a parent `div`, like this:

```css
.test {
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: cyan;
}

.parent-div {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <label class="test">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, itaque, at error rerum ab facere cupiditate veniam incidunt modi temporibus explicabo earum molestiae minima facilis a excepturi laborum similique dolore.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh you were faster then me :D

Comment: That bug report says the issue is "Resolved" and "Invalid", so I'm not sure it applies.